# How to create new user accounts from another (admin role) account in ASP.NET MVC 5 (Identity)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I have ASP.NET MVC 5 application (database first) with standard user profile management provided by Identity 2.
 There is an **account with admin role** and I need to create functionality for management (CRUD) of another user accounts (to set name, email, password, role and some other parameters **from another (admin) user account**, that have Admin role) via the web interface.
How to create new user accounts from another account(admin role)?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built in UserManager<TUser,TKey> to programmatically create users and add them to a particular role.

For example:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser {
    UserName = "new_user",
    Email = "user@gmail.com"
};
string password = "secret";

using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>(store);

    var result = manager.Create(user, password);
    if (!result.Succeeded)
        throw new ApplicationException("Unable to create a user.");

    result = manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Administrator");
    if (!result.Succeeded)
        throw new ApplicationException("Unable to add user to a role.");
}
```